# Link in php search results

Tags: php, hyperlink

Been trying different ways of displaying links as hypertext in my php search results. Displaying the link as text works but not as a clickable link.

I found a solution here and it works but not in the way I want. 
As it is now the link "Follow link here" works but if there is no link in database it still give "Follow link here" with the content https://mywebsite/mysearch.php?query=[MY SEARCH]. That is; it gives a link to the results.

Any help appreciated!

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("X", "Y", "Z") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($con,"X") or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES UTF8");


$query = $_GET['query']; 
$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

$raw_results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Library WHERE (`Tablettes` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Title` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Author` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Language` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Subject` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Subject2` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Translation` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `About` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY Lopnr ASC") or die(mysqli_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){

echo "<p><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' width='900' align='center' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' border='0'>

<thead>
<hr align='center' width='900'>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr><center><font color='#ffffff'>
Library: <strong>".$results['Library']."</strong></br>
<tr><center>".$results['CategoryYear']."
</tr>
</em></td></tr>
```

// EDITED //

```
<tr>
<td style='border-right:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;border-top:none' colspan='10' valign='top'>
<em>
echo '<a href=".$results['Link'].">Follow link here</a>'
</td></tr>

</tbody>
</body>
</html>
</table>";

    }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ 
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}

?>
```

Comment: Hm, only display that line if `$results['Link']` has content? (Also I think you can remove the `echo '` around it)

Comment: Ok. Removed echo :-). Yes, only display link if it has content in database.

Comment: Your example code format does not look nice. If you want help you must clarify your codes. Can you try ``<a href="' . $results['Link'] . '">Follow link here</a>``

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total novice and have built this by copying from others. I don't really understand how it works :-). 
Trying that code gives: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' . $results['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in mysite/search.php on line 87

Comment: replace this `echo '<a href=".$results['Link'].">Follow link here</a>'` to `<a href=".$results['Link'].">Follow link here</a>`

Comment: That works, but still I get links evens if "Link" is empty in database. And that links to the page of the searchresults.

Comment: You have a lot of broken html tags fix them and add and `if($result['link'])` before printing link if you don't want a blank `href` on anchor tag

Comment: You mean like this:
    if($results['Link']
    <a href=".$results['Link']."> Follow link here</a>
 ? …
That gives:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after `while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){` place the following code:

```
$link = '';
if (! empty($results['Link']) ) {
  $link = '<em><a href='.$results['Link'].'>Follow link here</a></em>';
}
```

Then in your `// EDITED //` part, replace

```
<em>
echo '<a href=".$results['Link'].">Follow link here</a>'
```

with just `$link`.

Comment: Thanks! But then I get:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Link' (T_STRING)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, had the wrong quotes there. Edited my code

Comment: No problem, glad it works ;) (Remember to accept this as answer if it solved your problem)